# Google Maps Android API (Latest Dec 8, 2014 Release) Centralizing Around User's Location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working on a few POC (Proof of Concept) applications to help me build my larger application.
I'll be straightforward. I am just trying to have my application, which has a map as the main activity, open on centered upon the user's current location.

Below my code is getting an error due to a NullPointerException when I try to move the camera - because mLastLocation is null.
Again, whenever my application opens up I want it to be centered about the user's location.
I'm following the newest release (December 8, 2014) of Google Maps Android API v2.

I would like not to have to create a GoogleMap member variable.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance to whoever helps solve my issue.

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

protected static final String TAG = "Application";
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected Location mLastLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), 13)); //<-- NullPointerException

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think extending it from `FragmentActivity` instead of `MainActivity` would solve your problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
...
}
```

And for XML layout class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of my utilisation of Google Map in my application:

in layout/map.xml :

```
   <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/location_map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

and in my MapFragment.java :

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap map;

public MapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.location_map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap(); 
    if (map == null)
    {
        return v;
    }
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false); 
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    if (map == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Google Maps not available",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return v;
    }

    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());


    LatLng location =  new LatLng(51.5033630,-0.1276250);
    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

     Marker market =  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(location)
            .title("My marker")
            .snippet("desc");

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(ProfileManager.getLatitude(),
            ProfileManager.getLongitude()), 13);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
return v;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
}
```

Hope it helps !